# An AI library or SDK which supports neural networks to get started

Tags: library, artificial-intelligence, sdk

I am new to AI and to get started I want to train a neural network using simple values.

My input values are: 1, 2, 3, ...
And my output values: 1*1, 2*2, 3*3, ... (1, 4, 9, ...)

It's simply `f(x) = x^2`

I am looking for a library or SDK which supports real neural networks. I don't want to use regression but instead a neural network.

I want to train the neural network without giving it any hint about what kind of mathematical function is being used. It is ok if I have to tell it that it is a mathematical function. But I don't want to tell it whether it's linear,  polynomial or exponential.

I tried php-ml but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75034806/php-ml-regression-predicts-weird-values) post I was told it doesn't support neural networks.

I am good at these languages: PHP, Java, JavaScript, C, C++.

Please recommend a library or SDK in one of these languages. If there is none then C# would also be fine.

It must run under Linux and it must be free. It must run locally and not in the cloud.

Comment: You may also want to post/ssearch on: https://ai.stackexchange.com/ and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could install **Weka** - it is a free desktop app ([Download](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka/)) and it has all classic supervised learning algorithms [built in](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/) (or extendable via a package manager). Learning algorithms include Linear Regression, Multilayer convolutional neural network (which you can design by point and click), Simple Perceptron; and unsupervised learning algorithms , too.

The output will not be "most likely functionname = f(x²)" but you will get  confusion matrices and metrics like accuracy, false positive rate, mean of squared errors, f-measure.

You could use the "Weka Experimenter" Component to try several possible algorithms at once. Then you must finally select an appropriate model (or data transformation) by choosing the one with the best metrics.

Drawbacks of Weka are its non-intuitive User interface (Watch some tutorial videos first), Weka is Java based (extra installation steps required), and it works best with its own input file format (.arff), although .csv files work as well.

Comment: I googled a little and it seems Weka can only do nn classification using the class MultilayerPerceptron. It cannot produce integers as output (see my example). If I am wrong then please tell me which Weka class I have to use.

Comment: You are not wrong and I don't know _that_ much about neural networks but I think a neural network classification never directly  gives you integers as output. It  assigns probabilities to each potential classification outcome. In the well-known tutorial Neural Networks , e.g. for classifying MNIST digits, the neural network never gives you "0" or "4" or "7" as output, it gives you a vector of probabilites p (or likelihoods) for each digit from 0-9 and you choose the p which is max.  -- Maybe you are looking for something different (an ai-assisted computer algebra system, perhaps)?

Comment: I gave you the bounty for your effort. I found TensorFlow which seems to be deep learning library #1.

Comment: Thanks. I like to have Weka (and Netlogo) at my disposal, because they are desktop apps and I come from an era where this was the dominant paradigm for working with a computer. For having all classic machine-learning algorithms "under one roof", and for having an interactive point-and click GUI, Weka is good. (Some simple routine tasks are super-awkward to execute though. Too many clicks required.). Good luck with tensorflow (use the Keras "add-on") .